# How can i add N user inputs into a list using a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, append

```
question = ""
while question not in questionList:
    question = questionList.append(input("Whats your question? "))
    if question in questionList:
        break
    elif question == "none":
        break
```

What I am trying to do is to have the user ask a question repeatedly until either input "none" or until they repeat themselves. The things they input should go into the "questionList" list The only problem is that my code doesn't break no matter what. How can I get the while loop to break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
question = "_"
questionList=[]
while question != "":
    question = str(input("Whats your question? "))
    if question == None or question in questionList:
        break
    questionList.append(question) # returns None
```

Comment: thanks for that but this solution also causes the loop to break after just one input. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Right fixing... and fixed. The problem was  the loop condition. Of course the new question is inserted and immediately recognized as already present.

Comment: Ok so now it allows me to answer the question but after only one answer it wnds the loop. Also your solution has question ="" instead of questionList = [] just so you know. any more ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that `questionList.append()` always returns `None` whereas your code seems to assume that it returns its argument. Rephrase as follows:

```
question = input("Whats your question? ")
questionList.append(question)
```

Comment: i would add a recommendation to OP and use `raw_input` instead of `input` since it seems like all the manipulation and input type is string.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I've edited that, the while loop breaks immediately without allowing me to add anything more to the list

Comment: @Javonne: Think carefully about how and when your `while` condition gets evaluated. :) If it helps, work through a couple of iterations of your loop using pen and paper, and hopefully things will become clear.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean? Thanks anyway!